Prior on the number of features for a bayesian model
I am training a bayesian model for predicting a binary outcome (case/control). There are hundreds of features that could be included, which were previously ranked using an unrelated procedure. However, I don't know which of them are relevant and which are not. Thus, I can train the models with $5, 6, 7... n$ features.
My current approach to choising the number of features is to use cross-validation - the model that has the best AUC is taken as the best. This is a frequentist way of doubg things and I would like to complement it with a fully bayesian approch, in comparing the evidence of models with different number of parameters. This requires choosing a prior on the number of features - presumably models with more features are less probable...
What are the standard priors for such cases?
